# Can we use 'initState' two time in a code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How Can we use 'initState' two time in a code, after doing it i get this error :

The name 'initState' is already defined. Try renaming one of the declarations.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense. Please read more about `initState` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use the `initState` method twice.

The framework will call the `initState` method exactly once for each State object it creates.

Read more about `initState` in the Flutter documentation, I've provided a link below:

[initState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)